# Get value from input box in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

This the code in my .aspx page and I am using auto complete for textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Preferences.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'Name':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>


<table style="width:auto">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please Type Student Name:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="autosuggest" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=txtsearch Visible="true" class="autosuggest"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I put runat="Server" in

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="autosuggest" />
```

then auto complete doesn't work. Form tag is used in master page.

**Problem Solved** using the name property of control

Source Code:

```
    <input type="text" name="_name"  />

    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" onclick="btnShow_Click" />
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string strValue = Page.Request.Form["_name"].ToString();
    Response.Write(strValue);
 }
```

Reference: http://www.etechpulse.com/2013/02/get-html-input-controls-value-server.html

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Do you want to cal it in a page load? and check in console are you getting any error?

Comment: You are performing an ajax operation. This will not re-render your entire page.  You will need to load the response values to the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MasterPage then ASP.net will auto generate a name for each control and appends it to your control, In order to get the unique ID of the control you need to use JQuery ClientID.

Put `runat="server"` but change your jquery function to (this will retrieve the input by ClientID):

```
 function SearchText() {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
```

Or as an alternative(suggested by DeeMac) use static [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx).

Comment: It's also a viable alternative to look into using static ClientIDMode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: Thanks @DeeMac will add that to my answer :)

Comment: @user2345661 after making the change put an alert see if it fires?

Answer (score 0):

For getting value form text box, you need to use server control.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

you can also add **ClientIDMode= "static"** in the server control to retain your id exactly same or you can use  `$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>")` to get the dynamicaly generated Id.

Comment: I couldn't get server control to work with class="autosuggest".